# CSS footer covering up bottom of page

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a footer I want to stay at the bottom of the page so you have to scroll down to the bottom of the page to see it, for some reason it is covering up part of the page, I'm fairly certain it is an issue with the footer, when I commented it out the issue went away, here is the CSS for the footer:

```
   /*Footer*/
.footer-distributed{
    background-color: #292c2f;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font: bold 16px sans-serif;

    padding: 55px 50px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 50px;/*or just height:50px;*/
  margin-top: auto;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* Footer left */

.footer-distributed .footer-left{
    width: 40%;
}

/* The company logo */

.footer-distributed h3{
    color:  #ffffff;
    font: normal 36px 'Cookie', cursive;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed h3 span{
    color:  #5383d3;
}

/* Footer links */

.footer-distributed .footer-links{
    color:  #ffffff;
    margin: 20px 0 12px;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
    color:  #8f9296;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Footer Center */

.footer-distributed .footer-center{
    width: 35%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i{
    background-color:  #33383b;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i.fa-envelope{
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p span{
    display:block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:2;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p a{
    color:  #5383d3;
    text-decoration: none;;
}


/* Footer Right */

.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    width: 20%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about{
    line-height: 20px;
    color:  #92999f;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about span{
    display: block;
    color:  #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons{
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:  #33383b;
    border-radius: 2px;

    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;

    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* If you don't want the footer to be responsive, remove these media queries */

@media (max-width: 880px) {

    .footer-distributed{
        font: bold 14px sans-serif;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-left,
    .footer-distributed .footer-center,
    .footer-distributed .footer-right{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-center i{
        margin-left: 0;
    }

}
```

In case the issue is with something else here is some other CSS:

```
  html {
    line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/* Sections
     ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the margin in all browsers.
 */

body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

And finally:

```
.container-history{
padding-left: 10%;
padding-right: 10%;
overflow: visible;
```

}

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
Here is a CodePen.io Link https://codepen.io/Pagaley12/pen/JBLmrJ

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's rather difficult to answer this question without being able to see how your existing page is rendered. It would help if you could update your question to list **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, could you please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Add padding to the bottom of your `body` that is the same size as the height of your footer.

Comment: I added a link to the codepen, @ObsidianAge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set an element to position absolute, it is decoupled from the flow of the page. Meaning it doesn't take any height on the page. So the page ends when the main content ends.

To fix your issue, add a margin at the end of the main content. In your case it is `.content-area`.

```
.content-area {
  margin-bottom:230px
}
```

Find the correct margin value that works for your case.

Example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjxzzQ)

Answer (score 0):

Add the property `position: relative;` to the class `footer-distributed` and this will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple fix.

```
/*Footer*/

.footer-distributed{

background-color: #292c2f;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
font: bold 16px sans-serif;

padding: 55px 50px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 50px;/*or just height:50px;*/
  margin-top: auto;

}
```

The footer's position should be **relative**. It will come or displayed after the main content is over. Absolute stays and blocks the content.

You can give it a height so it won't behave weirdly in mobile view.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp